# Spectrometer resolution in Atomic Spectra

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hyperfine-structure

As we try to refine our spectrometer better and better each day, like first we observed doublets in Hydrogen atom, then we observed fine structure's in hydrogen like and in many heavy elements. Then we saw hyper fine splitting too where atomic nucleus takes part too. My question is what will happen in the case where we have a spectrometer and we are observing one single line of a particular spectrum which is so sharp that (till my knowledge I know splitting till hyper-fine level) will we observe a single a infinite sharp line or what. Or there will be some error like Doppler broadening etc. kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

The measure of "sharpness" of a spectral feature is the line-width of the transition. In the context of atomic spectra, Doppler effects as well as others may cause an artificial broadening of the line to be measured, but there is also natural broadening imposed by the Time-Energy uncertainty principle.

The Time-Energy uncertainty principle relates the lifetime of an excited state to the uncertainty in the energy difference between the excited state and that of lower energy states that it can decay to. The lower the uncertainty in the energy difference, the greater the lifetime of the transition. An infinitely sharp transition would correspond to an infinite lifetime, which is effectively a forbidden transition that would therefore not be measured.